# How to convert the Video file to byte array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I need to convert a video file to byte array and then send the byte array to a server, but when I upload the byte array the server did not receive it in the correct format. I convert the file like below:-

```java
buffer=new byte[1024];
os=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);
int read;
while ((read=fis.read(buffer))!=-1){
    os.write(buffer,0,read);
}
fis.close();
os.close();
```

Comment: At the end you hava `os.toByteArray()` (`byte[]`) you may send. Or better get the OutputStream of the server to write to, as that byte array will be huge.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the ways to convert the file into byte[]

First

```java
File file = new File(path);
int size = (int) file.length();
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
buf.close();
```

Second

```java
byte bytes[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
dis.readFully(bytes);
```

Third

```java
byte bytes[] = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(photoFile)
```

The only drawback is to add this dependency in your build.gradle app :

```java
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
File file = new File("filepath");
//init array with file length
byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()]; 

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
fis.read(bytesArray); //read file into bytes[]
fis.close();
return bytesArray;
```

Try this! hopefully it will work.